Are stone aggregate fines and screenings the same thing?
When talking about the dust/powder in crushed limestone aggregates, I've heard people use the words "fines" and "screenings". Do the two words mean the same thing in this context?


Yes.  There may be slightly different gradations, depending on locale.
